# selenium and lxml - how to set html?

Tags: python, selenium, lxml

I have a script that parses a document and changes form values with lxml.  Now I want to use selenium to navigate to the page and do it.

Unfortunately selenium doesn't seem to be advanced enough support some of the things I'm doing in lxml, for example, "if 'attrName' in tag.attrib"

Then I said, "Aha!, But selenium provides webdriver.page_source where I can get the html!"
Yeah, sort of... I can get it, then parse it with lxml... but annoyingly, page_source is not writeable so I cannot persist my changes!

I still feel like I'm on the right path with that, but is there some way I can write the modified html back to the browser?

UPDATE: 
I tried several ways of trying to rewrite all page contents, but the firefox webdriver started throwing security exceptions like it didn't like the looks of what I was trying to do.  Below I'll post the alternative I used instead.

Comment: selenium can use xpath like lxml. And if it can't find something then it raise error and you can use `try/except` to catch it - so you can use it instead of `"if 'attrName' in tag.attrib"` OR use `if item.get_attribute('attrName')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wound up doing was to create an lxml-like intermediary class.  This implements only those features which I needed, but still, I thought I'd share as a starting point for others trying to do the same thing.

```
import lxml.etree
import collections.abc


class AttribWrapper(collections.abc.MutableMapping):
    """
    Make something that acts like a dict to use as a mock lxml.etree.element attrib value

    see also:
        https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?emulating-container-types#emulating-container-types
    """
    def __init__(self,seleniumTag):
        self.seleniumTag=seleniumTag
        while not hasattr(seleniumTag,'execute_script'):
            seleniumTag=seleniumTag.parent
        self.webdriver=seleniumTag

    def hasAttribute(self,attrName):
        """
        determine if a tag has an attribute
        """
        try:
            val=self.seleniumTag.get_attribute(attrName)
        except Exception:
            return False
        return val is not None

    def getAttribute(self,attrName,default=None):
        """
        get a tag's attribute or default if not present
        """
        try:
            return self.seleniumTag.get_attribute(attrName)
        except Exception:
            pass
        return default

    def setAttribute(self,attrName,attrValue):
        """
        get a tag's attribute
        """
        self.webdriver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1],arguments[2]);",self.seleniumTag,attrName,attrValue);

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        if key not in self.keys():
            raise KeyError()
        return self.getAttribute(key)

    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        self.setAttribute(key,value)

    def __delitem__(self,key):
        self.webdriver.execute_script('arguments[0].attributes.removeNamedItem("%s");'%key,self.seleniumTag)

    def __iter__(self):
        items=[]
        for k in self.keys():
            v=self[k]
            items.append((k,v))
        return self.keys().__iter__()

    def __len__(self):
        return self.webdriver.execute_script('return arguments[0].attributes.length',self.seleniumTag)

    def keys(self):
        n=self.webdriver.execute_script('return arguments[0].attributes.length',self.seleniumTag)
        names=[]
        for idx in range(n):
            result=self.webdriver.execute_script('return arguments[0].attributes.item(%d).nodeName'%idx,self.seleniumTag)
            names.append(result)
        return names

    def __repr__(self):
        ret=[]
        for k,v in self.items():
            ret.append('("%s":"%s")'%(k,v))
        return "{%s}"%(', '.join(ret))


class LikeEtreeElement:

    def __init__(self,seleniumTag):
        self.seleniumTag=seleniumTag
        self.attrib=AttribWrapper(seleniumTag)
        while not hasattr(seleniumTag,'execute_script'):
            seleniumTag=seleniumTag.parent
        self.webdriver=seleniumTag

    @property
    def tag(self):
        return self.seleniumTag.tag_name

    def getchildren(self):
        """
        get all child elements
        (NOTE: this will dip into the html every single time just
            in case things have changed.)
        """
        return self.seleniumTag.find_elements_by_xpath('/*')

    @property     
    def innerHTML(self):
        return self.webdriver.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerHTML',self.seleniumTag)
    @innerHTML.setter
    def innerHTML(self,value):
        value=str(value).replace('\\\\','\\').replace('\n','\\n').replace('"','\\"')
        return self.webdriver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML="%s"'%(value),self.seleniumTag)

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        return self.getchildren()[idx]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.getchildren().__iter__()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.getchildren())
```